# Crosswalk WebRTC for WebOS TV

Tags: webrtc, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, webos, crosswalk

I am currently developing a TV app with Samsung's TOAST, which generates packages for both Tizen and WebOS TVs.

I am going to have to implement a WebRTC flow for realtime streaming.

I just found out that Crosswalk, which allows juste that (among other things), will be supported in next Tizen SDK.

My question is: would anyone know if Crosswalk will also be supported in Samsung's TOAST and work on WebOS TVs?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, though webOS also does WebRTC natively with its built in browser.